# Graphical disk surface check tool?

Tags: partitioning

I need a program that can scan my hard drive for read and write errors so I can partition around them. I REALLY don't do well with numbers but if I can have something that shows an output like the graphical display on gparted that would be perfect. I know a lot of people would recommend replacing the disk but right now I can't as I NEED this laptop for school and can't wait for a hard drive to arrive (I have ordered one, yes, but I don't expect it to arrive for another couple weeks as I only figured out afterwards they still have to manufacture it)

Comment: I can't find a tool that shows bad sectors graphically, but `gsmartcontrol` and the built-in Disks utility are two GUI ways to look at the SMART data for a disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HDD should have remapped such sectors on its own, but in case it doesn't:
Most filesystems know how to work around bad sectors, if these bad sectors are marked as such. The program `badblocks` does this for you, but it's not a GUI program.

Another thing worth mentioning: Your new HDD doesn't have to be manufactured, I'm 99% sure that this is either an outright lie or a poor excuse from your dealer. HDDs are standardized commodities and nothing special.

Comment: I ordered a really nice hybrid drive directly from hitachi, that's why it still needs to be manufactured

Comment: Yeah, why not - but this kind of surprises me: Are you sure that this type of HDD isn't available and on stock somewhere else?